# How to sort list of classes, as if they were integers in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of class objects:

```
list = [x, y, z]
```

But I want to sort them like integers (they have an integer variable defined in them that I want to sort by (I access it by doing list[x].score)), but I don't know how to.

How can I sort this? (the list has a variable length)

Ideally, something like this:

```
list = [x, y, z]  # x.score = 2, y.score = 3, z.score = 1
list.sort()  # Or something
# list = [z, x, y]
```

Comment: It is very important to understand, "class objects" means the classes themselves. You mean *instances of a class*, although note, `int` objects are instances of a class, the class `int`...  *Everything in Python is an instance of a class (even classes themselves)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `key=` keyword argument of the [`.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method. All you do is pass it a function or lambda that returns what you really want to sort the objects by:

```
lst = [x, y, z]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x.score)
```

Or, here's a fuller example:

```
class ScoreHolder:
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.score)


lst = [ScoreHolder(2), ScoreHolder(3), ScoreHolder(1)]
print(lst)

lst.sort(key=lambda x: x.score)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

`sorted_list = sorted(objslist, key=lambda obj:obj.score)`